# Horizontally buttons alignment

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to fix this strange behaviour, see image:
[image]

Here the code I used, it's a simple callout:

```
    <div class="${dispatch.getType()}">
    <h5>${dispatch.getType()}</h5>
    <p>${dispatch.getMessage()}</p>            
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${dispatch.getServlet()}? 
    ${dispatch.getActionParameter()}=${dispatch.getDeleteID()}&${dispatch.getState()}=1" 
    class="button">submit</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" class="button">cancel and go back</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I put the buttons inside a form, they are aligned now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough I put the buttons inside a form and now they are aligned.